# DB2 equivalent of T-SQL's Output Clause

Tags: sql, db2, sql-update

I'm looking for a way for my query to return a value that it increments in a table.

For example:

```
UPDATE Items SET Clicks = Clicks + 1
```

I need this query to return the new value of "Clicks" that it has set.

The [T-SQL Output Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) seems to suit my purposes, but I can't find a DB2 equivalent. Is there a way I could accomplish this in DB2, without using a second query?

Comment: I think you're going to want to use a stored procedure.  There's a way to do this with an `insert`, but there doesn't appear to be the equivalent for the `update`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by using FINAL TABLE data change table reference:

```
SELECT Clicks
FROM FINAL TABLE ( UPDATE Items SET Clicks = Clicks + 1 )
```

You can view more documentation [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0011133.html).

Comment: To anyone using DB2 for i -- this does not work in DB2 for i v7R1.